# При запуске приложения текст в TextView в одну строку

Tags: android

При запуске приложения на устройстве, текст который разбит по строкам, пишется в одну строку(все слитно)
Разметка `TextView`:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPrimerCeil"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/primer1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

и файл `string.xml`

```
<string name="primer1"><font color = '#4682b4'> import</font> math
    number = <font color = '#9b2d30' >-8.10</font>
    print(<font color = '#19ff19'>"Верхний предел 8.10 это:"</font>math.ceil(number))
    print(<font color = '#19ff19'>"Нижний предел предел 8.10 это:"</font>math.floor(number))
    <font color = '#808080' >Вывод</font>
    Верхний предел 8.10 это: 9
    Нижний предел 8.10 это: 8
</string>
```

Как должно быть:
[image: Пример]

Comment: Пробовали добавить '\n' для переноса строки? В большинстве ситуаций это работает.  
Так же возможно существует `println` или что-то подобное, чтоб вставлять с переносом строки

Comment: @Dafter, Спасибо, получилось. Есть ли еще какие-то способы переноса строки?

Comment: Честно говоря никогда не работал с котлином под андройд, потому без понятия. Если ты не против, можешь написать какой конкретно способ сработал, чтоб я мог добавить это, как ответ

Comment: @Dafter. Через \n. Не знаю почему я сразу не додумался =D

Comment: Ну бывает. Пометьте мой ответ как решение пожалуйста, и хорошего вам программирования :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `\n` - универсальный вариант при работе со строками